# Backbone global model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can i fetch the model only once and keep it for rendering with different conditions?

```
define(
    ["backbone", "jquery", "app/config", "app/TemplateManager", "app/User"],
    function(Backbone, $, config, TemplateManager, User) {

        var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName: "div",
            className: "window-header",
            User: new User,

            events: {
            },


            initialize: function() {
                var User = this.User;
                if(!(this.model instanceof Backbone.Model)) {
                    this.model = User;
                }

                this.listenTo(Backbone, "dialog:open", this.dialogOpen);
                this.listenTo(Backbone, "contacts:open", this.contactsOpen);
                this.listenTo(Backbone, "window:close", this.restoreDefaults);

                this.restoreDefaults();
                // this.render();
            },


            render: function() {
                var self = this;
                TemplateManager.get("window-header", function(template) {

                    self.model.validate();
                    self.$el.html(template(self.model.toJSON()));

                    $("#window").prepend(self.$el);
                });

                return this;
            },


            dialogOpen: function(contact) {
                this.model.set(contact.attributes);
                this.render();
            },


            contactsOpen: function() {
                if(!this.User.has("id")) {
                    var self = this;
                    this.User.fetch({
                        success: function(model, response, options) {
                            self.model.set(self.User.attributes);
                            self.render();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    this.model.set(this.User.attributes);
                    this.render();
                }
            },


            restoreDefaults() {
                this.model.set(this.User.defaults());
                this.render();
            },

        });

        return HeaderView;
    }
);
```

So in my application it should be 3 states of WindowHeader

1. default restoreDefaults()
2. render with Contact model attributes dialogOpen()
3. render with User data contactsOpen()

I don't whant to fetch User data every time is it posible to do it once and store it in some variable?
But when I call restoreDefaults() every time my this.User also cleared to default.
Why?
Why this.User equals to this.model?
Even if I do this

```
var User = this.User;
this.model = User;
```

Is it equal?

```
this.model = this.User
```

I suppose doesn't. Am I wrong?
What can I do?

Comment: Just a side note, `var User = this.User;` is not a common practice. In common naming convention, only constructors are named with a capital letter... Ideally it should be `var user = this.user;`, unless you are referring to actual model constructor instead of an instance...

Answer (score 1):

You `this.model` and `User` is the same object(the same reference).

The good practice is that that you no need to keep `User` in this View. No need to do this `User: new User`.

No need to set new data to model `this.model.set(this.User.defaults());`
I think you shouldn't mutate User model. If need you can create another model and don't touch User Model directly.

NOTE: `new HeaderView({model: User})`. model param is special option, if passed, will be attached directly to the view. So you can access in view `this.model`

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I have to clone for get new model instance

```
this.model = this.User.clone();
```

Comment: Do you actually need clones of a model instance for rendering? You can do `toJSON()` and get a plain JS object with the data, which will be faster and take less memory

Comment: Yes i need. After it should be validated this.model.validate()